# CorsConfigurationSource required type error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I was trying to set CORS configs to my Spring Boot application globally in order not to use @CrossOrigin annotation in each controller or endpoint. As far as I checked  [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/cors.html#page-title) and stackoverflow, the way setting custom CORS configs is like:

```
  @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new
                UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

and finally using it in SecurityFilterChain like:

```
 @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                //.cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(
                        AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable 
                )
    //Some more configurations...
        return http.build();
    }
```

This code block should be fine according to other usages but it gives me:

**Required type: CorsConfigurationSource
Provided: UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource**

error due to return type of CorsConfigurationSource bean. Casting does not work either.

I am using Spring Boot 3.1.0.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. It is kinda silly but can help the people who encounter the same problem:

I was importing **UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource** from:

`import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;`

Instead of

`import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;`

So, you shouldn't import it from reactive package.